# How to change content of a Div on clicking image link?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I am creating a layout with two Columns.

One having images and second content. Now I want, whenever user clicks on image the content in the second column get changed.

HTML

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row" style="width: 75%;margin: 0 auto;">
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="p1"><span id="image1"><b>Planning</b></span></a>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="p2"><span id="image2"><b>Results</b></span></a>         
             </div>
           </div><br>
           <div class="row" style="width: 75%;margin: 0 auto;">
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="p3"><span id="image3"><b>Improvements</b></span></a>            
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="#"  class="p4"><span id="image4"><b>Communication</b></span></a>              
             </div>
           </div>
<div class="st">
            <div class="planning">
            <h3>Planning</h3>           
            <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
            Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
            making it work for them. </p>   
            </div>  

            <div class="results">
            <h3>Results</h3>            
            <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
            Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
            making it work for them. </p>   
            </div>

            <div class="improvements">
            <h3>Improvements</h3>           
            <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
            Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
            making it work for them. </p>   
            </div>

            <div class="communication">
            <h3>Communication</h3>          
            <p class="why-text">Search Marketing Group is a leader in creating unique Seo&nbsp;strategies that would help your website rank on page 1 of 
            Google for your most competitive keywords in your niche. We pride ourself on creating custom solutions for&nbsp;businesses and 
            making it work for them. </p>   
            </div>              
          </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 how-text">

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.st { display:none; }
.how-text { min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #e6ebe4; 
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 25px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 3px; }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.p1').click(function(){
    $('.how-text').html($('.planning').html());
});

    $('.p2').click(function(){
    $('.how-text').html($('.results').html());
});

    $('.p3').click(function(){
    $('.how-text').html($('.improvements').html());
});

    $('.p4').click(function(){
    $('.how-text').html($('.communication').html());
});
});
```

Try yourself in Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/19suymt4/

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Didn't get you dude.

Comment: I am trying to change the content in a div by clicking on Image and It's not working.. So can you help?

Comment: Its working!! **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/19suymt4/1/)**!! except you forgot to add `jquery.js` reference

Comment: Can you give me links to default jquery files? I'll add them in header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Editted**

Here is the easiest way of doing that with

```
getElementsByClassName
```

I changed your code for your understanding

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/19suymt4/4/)

Comment: Pleas check my answer again and remove alert msgs i put them for your understanding.

Comment: Great !!! It worked.. Thanks a ton buddy... Just 2 things.. 

1. On Improvements & Communications it's showing results text only
2. How to make to stick the div area? On click it takes the user to top of the page...

Comment: and is there any way to show the first one by default? As I don't want empty column there..

Comment: Opppss .. My bad,.. It's working now..

Just help me on... keeping the first div by default i.e the planning one..

Comment: here you go brother i used on load method of html which starts when html start see by your self its done like a charm
[See this Demo click here](https://jsfiddle.net/19suymt4/6/)

**pleas up vote my anwer and this solution thanks**

Comment: Super Cool !... Thanks mate.. It actually worked like magic.. Thanks a lot..BTW I am girl.

Comment: Your welcome and kindly up vote my answers it would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Did that already... Once I'll earn 15 reputation.. It'll start showing up. Thanks Again.

Comment: I think you got much repu to upvote my answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can access inside of a div as it has display none.
you can use

```
.st {height:0;overflow:hidden;}
```

instead of display:none

https://jsfiddle.net/19suymt4/2/

it can be your solution

Comment: Thanks It's Working in fiddle now. But not yet on my site. Can you tell me how to add jquery version 1.6.4 That could be the reason....

Comment: It's working now.. the only issue is.. I want default text to appear instead of blank space. https://jsfiddle.net/19suymt4/4/

Answer (score 0):

You did not added jquery in your code. Also you can narrow down the 4 click events to single click event:

```
 $('a').click(function () {
   $('.how-text').html($('.st div:eq('+$('.row > div').index($(this).parent())+')').html());
 });
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ryqorz1j/)**

Comment: @SargamGupta: add this script in your head section `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Milind.. But it's yet not doing anything... Don't know where I am writing the code wrong..